# Jupyter ImportError with import faker

Tags: python, jupyter

I am having an issue running jupiter and the error message i get is :

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-1ef24f389812> in <module>()
      5 import random
      6 from datetime import date, timedelta
----> 7 import faker
      8 # 2
      9 fake = faker.Faker()
```

I have no idea how to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

nevermind, I was missing the faker library?  just used python -m pip install faker